# What is the relation between zuul rate-limiting and hystrix isolation strategy?

Tags: java, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, rate-limiting

Hystrix isolation strategy includes thread isolation and semaphore isolation. Zuul uses semaphore isolation by default.

But I see there is libs like marcosbarbero's spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit which can be used to do rate-limiting on zuul.

I'm wondering the relation between  zuul rate-limiting and hystrix isolation strategies. For example, since there is semaphore isolation settings by default, which limits the number of conccurrent outgoing requests, if this is below zuul rate-limiting threshold, I think zuul rate-limiting threshold won't take effect? so if we want marcosbarbero's spring-cloud-zuul-ratelimit take effect, we should set semaphore isolation threshold to a maximum value?